# Function parameter in swift to accept array or string

Tags: swift

I want to write a function named `remove` in Swift which will accept an array or a string and remove the string from a dictionary if it is a string else it will remove all the strings from the dictionary which are present in the array. Also, this function that I wrote is disabling the styles in the editor of Xcode.

```
func remove(key: AnyObject){
    if key is Array{
        for (index, value) in enumerate(key){
            if -1 < self._getDataStoreKeyIndex(value){
               self._removeProperty(value)
            } else{
                self._removeItem(value)
            }
        }
    }else{
        if -1 < self._getDataStoreKeyIndex(key){
           self._removeProperty(key)
        }else{
            self._removeItem(key)
       }
    }
}
```

The other functions in the code are correct because if I comment this function my project is building successfully. What is wrong in my code?

I am getting a segmentation fault.

```
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: What's the question and/or the problem?

Comment: This function is not working. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: You need to give more details... what's not working? bad result? exception?

Comment: I am getting a segmentation fault. I edited the question.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the beginning of the function then step through the code to see exactly where it crashes.

Comment: It is not building. So, using breakpoints are not helping.

Comment: You have to be using Generics instead of simply using Array. How does that even compile, you should be using Array<Int> or [Int] or so on, Moreover use as to typecast the variable which will typecast to array if the object is array. if theKey = key as? [String]{ }

Answer (score 1):

The heart of the problem is attempting to convert to "Array" which is a generic class.  Instead, you need to convert to a specific instantiation of the generic, in your case "Array" or "[String]"

You also have a problem in that you can't enumerate AnyObject, combined, you need something like:

```
func remove(key: AnyObject) {
    if let array = key as? Array<String> {
        for (index, value) in enumerate(array) {
        }
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

Although I'm not sure why you're using `enumerate` to get at the indices which you don't use for anything, faster and more legible to just iterate the array directly:

```
func remove(key: AnyObject) {
    if let array = key as? Array<String> {
        for value in array {
        }
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

One further thought... these two operations really aren't similar and don't really share much code.  Why not define to different functions that differ in signature:

```
func remove(key:String) {
}

func remove(array:[String]) {
    for string in array {
        remove[string]
    }
}
```

Which eliminates the possibility that somebody calls "remove(5)"